# How to stagger imageViews freely around a layout? (pic included)

Tags: android

I want to stagger images or buttons around a layout in an artsy way so that they look like this wall

Any ideas on which layout to use or how to do this ?

Thanks for any help

[image]

or like this wall
[image]

Comment: I think Google would be better suited to answer this. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I think thats JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

for this you can follow this.

1- Create a recycler view with staggered layoutmanager.

2- Every child of recycler view implements onDragListener. you will get onDragEnter and exit evnets from there.

3- call startDrag of view on long press of a view. Keep track of which child you are dragging.

4- on Drop event just swap the values.

This is just a thought. with some more logic around, you can implement this.

Comment: I think your thinking how to let the user do it? i just want it to be permanently set that way, like a menu of imageView buttons. Thats cool too though

Comment: My mistake.. An Staggered Grid View is nearest thing. have a look if you are not familiar with it. https://codeascraft.com/2014/01/13/android-staggered-grid/